# How to play Audio sound at startup automatically in GWT

Tags: audio, gwt

I want to play a sound at start of the GWT client app.

I used the following code

```
        import com.google.gwt.media.client.Audio;

        Audio   mistakeAudio;

        mistakeAudio=Audio.createIfSupported();
        if (mistakeAudio!=null) {           
            mistakeAudio.setSrc("waves/Gong.wav");              
            mistakeAudio.load();
            mistakeAudio.setLoop(true);
            mistakeAudio.play();
        }
```

I tested various variations, but finally the sound only plays, if before the command mistakeAudio.play() at least one mouse click happened on the client window. Not even
doing anything..
Is there a workaround - starting really only programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 instead:

```
<audio id="gong" autoplay>
  <source src="waves/Gong.wav" type="audio/wav">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

or use javascript for the autoplay:

```
<script>
  var audio = document.getElementById("gong");
  audio.autoplay = true;
  audio.load();
</script>
```

which you could also code in GWT with JsInterop and Elemental2:

```
HTMLAudioElement audio = (HTMLAudioElement) Document.getElementById("gong");
audio.autoplay = true;
audio.load();
```